# PHP ssh2_scp_send file permissions

Tags: php, scp

I am using the PHP function `ssh2_scp_send` to transfer files from one server to another. The interesting things is that if I write the permission in it's octal form (ie 0644) directly everything works fine. If I instead enclose this in inverted commas or use a variabel this does not work any more.

To be clearer:
This works: `ssh2_scp_send($conn, $localFile, $remoteFile, 0644);`

Does NOT work: `ssh2_scp_send($conn, $localFile, $remoteFile, "0644");`

Does NOT work: `$permission=0644;ssh2_scp_send($conn, $localFile, $remoteFile, $permission);`

Anybody has any idea why this is the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give [`decoct()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.decoct.php) a chance. I'm not sure this will work, but you can try.
One more thing you can try is to store permissions values into constants with `define()`

Comment: brilliant, this really pointed me in the right direction: i needed the octdec () function! thanks

Answer (score 1):

The string may be interpreted as decimal.

Also, what type is `$permission`? Try using `var_dump()` on it. It may be a string too.

```
$a = 0644;

$b = (int) "0644";

var_dump($a, $b); // int(420), int(644)
```

[See it on codepad.org](http://codepad.org/QUWvnNEG)

Comment: how do i convert 0644 to 420 as this seems to be what the system wants?

Comment: @Adrien Hingert Check out the `decoct()` ( [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475866/php-ssh2-scp-send-file-permissions/4475888#4475888) ).